# Eclipse build path for Java, packages aren't correct

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an Android library project I am trying to add to my build path that contains source (not a compiled jar).

I figured out how to go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path  -> Link Source, and then choose my library folder.

This correctly adds the folder to my Android project.  However, the linked library has a "package" line at the top of each source file, and Eclipse does NOT like this, saying "The declared package does not match the expected package".  The suggested fixes all involve modifying (to have the expected package declaration) or moving (to the declared package location) the library source files, which I do not think I want to do.

I have ZERO experience with packages OR Android libraries.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?  If at all possible I want to use the libraries as is, without modifying the source. Moving them doesn't seem all that useful, either (since then git might try to commit them, although I suppose I could put the whole directory in .gitignore).

What is the CORRECT way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an Android library project (the `Is Library` checkBox has been ticked in Project --> Properties --> Android section).

In your project, add it as a Library i.e, goto Properties --> Android --> Library --> add

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it just fine!  I ignored this option at first because the "Add Library" option was empty.  But when I imported the library into Android (didn't know I needed to do that), it showed up just fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to copy the project on to your workspace and then go to import and select existing android code.

also check you should check your SDK Management